# Where do you put your Rack middleware files and requires?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conventions, rack, middleware

I'm in the process of refactoring some logic built into a Rails application into middleware, and one annoyance I've run into is a seeming lack of convention for where to put them.

Currently I've settled on `app/middleware` but I could just as easily move it to `vendor/middleware` or maybe `vendor/plugins/middleware`...

The biggest problem is having to require the individual files at the top of `config/environment.rb`

```
require "app/middleware/system_message"
require "app/middleware/rack_backstage"
```

or else I get uninitialized constant errors on the `config.middleware.use` lines. That could get messy very quickly. I'd rather this was tucked away in an initializer somewhere.

Is there a conventional place to put this stuff?

---

The specific answer I'm looking for with this bounty is: **where can I put the require lines so that they are not cluttering the environment.rb file but still get loaded before the config.middleware.use calls?** Everything I have tried leads to uninitialized constant errors.

---

**Update**: Now that we're using Rails 3.0, I treat a Rails app like any other Rack app; code files for middleware go in `lib` (or a gem listed in `Gemfile`) and are required and loaded in `config.ru`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As of Rails 3.2, Rack middleware belongs in the app/middleware directory.

It works "out-of-the-box" without any explicit require statements.

Quick example:

I'm using a middleware class called **CanonicalHost** which is implemented in **app/middleware/canonical_host.rb**. I've added the following line to production.rb (**note** that the middleware class is explicitly given, rather than as a quoted string, which works for any environment-specific config files):

```
config.middleware.use CanonicalHost, "example.com"
```

If you're adding middleware to **application.rb**, you'll need to include quotes, as per [@mltsy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428343/where-do-you-put-your-rack-middleware-files-and-requires/9218725#comment38150011_9218725).

```
config.middleware.use "CanonicalHost", "example.com"
```

Comment: Could you please add any link for reference? It's not working out of the box for me and Google / Rails guides aren't helping ... thanks!

Comment: I got this working out of the box, after I realized I made a dumb mistake of placing it in my root folder instead of (the already specified) app folder. So, foo_app/app/middleware/file.rb.

Comment: I had to enclose my middleware class name in quotes to get this to work; see my answer below.

Comment: Note: this only works (without quotes) if you're adding middleware in an environment-specific file (i.e. `production.rb`) - if you want to add it to all environments by putting it in `application.rb`, you have to use quotes (or explicitly require the file that defines your class), because application.rb is one of the first things that is loaded - before any of the dynamic initialization code loads the `app/middleware` files.

Comment: Note, in Rails 5+ you can no longer use the String for the name of the middleware. You need to use the proper class name. Additionally, according to @rafaelfranca (Rails core), _"middleware can't be in app because they can't be reloaded. They should be in lib and if you put them in lib, require_relative will work."_ https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25525#issuecomment-479941866

Answer (score 24):

You can put it in `lib/tableized/file_name.rb`. As long as the class you're trying to load is discoverable by its filename, Rails will automatically load the file necessary. So, for example:

```
config.middleware.use "MyApp::TotallyAwesomeMiddleware"
```

You would keep in:

```
lib/my_app/totally_awesome_middleware.rb
```

Rails catches const_missing and attemts to load files corresponding to the missing constants automatically. Just make sure your names match and you're gravy. Rails even provides nifty helpers that'll help you identify the path for a file easily:

```
>> ChrisHeald::StdLib.to_s.tableize.singularize
=> "chris_heald/std_lib"
```

So my stdlib lives in `lib/chris_heald/std_lib.rb`, and is autoloaded when I reference it in code.

Comment: I have some middleware called `Rack::Backstage`. Put it in `lib/rack/backstage.rb`. Unititialized constant error.

Comment: This works _only_ if the first parameter is a string. Once I figured that out, success!

Answer (score 11):

In my Rails 3.2 app, I was able to get my middleware `TrafficCop` loading by putting it at `app/middleware/traffic_cop.rb`, just as @MikeJarema described. I then added this line to my `config/application.rb`, as instructed:

```
config.middleware.use TrafficCop
```

However, upon application start, I kept getting this error:

```
uninitialized constant MyApp::Application::TrafficCop
```

Explicitly specifying the root namespace didn't help either:

```
config.middleware.use ::TrafficCop
# uninitialized constant TrafficCop
```

For some reason (which I've yet to discover), at this point in the Rails lifecycle, `app/middleware` wasn't included in the load paths. If I removed the `config.middleware.use` line, and ran the console, I could access the `TrafficCop` constant without any issue. But it couldn't find it in `app/middleware` at config time.

I fixed this by enclosing the middleware class name in quotes, like so:

```
config.middleware.use "TrafficCop"
```

This way, I would avoid the `uninitialized constant` error, since Rails isn't trying to find the `TrafficCop` class just yet. But, when it starts to build the middleware stack, it will constantize the string. By this time, `app/middleware` is in the load paths, and so the class will load correctly.

Comment: I'm on rails 3.2.18 and have the same issue when I put this in application.rb - but when I put it in a specific environment config, then it worked fine!  IF you follow the load path starting with config.ru, it turns out application.rb is loaded before most other things, then the application is initialized (which loads all the dynamic initializers, including middlewares), and the other environment files are loaded after that, so by then the middleware constants are defined!

Comment: Note, in Rails 5+ you can no longer use the String for the name of the middleware. You need to use the proper class name. Additionally, according to @rafaelfranca (Rails core), _"middleware can't be in app because they can't be reloaded. They should be in lib and if you put them in lib, require_relative will work."_ https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25525#issuecomment-479941866

Answer (score 5):

For Rails 3:

```
#config/application.rb
require 'lib/rack/my_adapter.rb'
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Rack::MyAdapter
  end
end
```

Comment: This still works - and is better than all the other String answers - in Rails 5+ where they disallowed the use of Strings for the name of the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a convention, but why not put it in the `/lib` directory? Files in there get automatically loaded by Rails.

Comment: Not until after environment.rb is run, if at all. Moving them to lib didn't solve the uninitialized constant errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an initializer which requires the necessary files and then leave the files wherever you want.

According to [this](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/initialization.html) the initializers are executed before the rack middleware is loaded.

Comment: Looks like I was a bit optimistic when reading that. I guess config.ru doesn't match you requirements either ?

Comment: well, that would require using rackup instead of script/server, right? I could do that if I had to but I honestly thought it would be easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution I have so far is moving the middleware requires to `config/middleware.rb` and requiring that file in `environment.rb`, reducing it to a single require which I can live with.

I'd still like to hear how other people have solved this seemingly basic problem of adding middleware to Rails.