# Cannot load Rack Middleware file into Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rack

Trying to get Heroku's WebSocket tutorial working with a Rails app but the middleware is not loading.

Steps to reproduce:

- Created a Rails 3.2.15 app.
- Add `faye-websocket` gem and run `bundle install`
- Create `app/middleware` directory in the application
- Copy over the the following into `app/middleware/test_server.rb`

> ```
> require 'faye/websocket'
>
> class TestServer
>   KEEPALIVE_TIME = 15 # in seconds
>
>   def initialize(app)
>     @app     = app
>     @clients = []
>   end
>
>   def call(env)
>   end
> end
> ```

- Add the following to `config/application.rb`

> config.middleware.use TestServer

- Run `rails console`

I see the following error:

> config/application.rb:64:in `': uninitialized constant RackMiddleware::Application::TestServer (NameError)

If I add `require 'test_server'`, I see the following error:

> config/application.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- test_server (LoadError)

I thought an directories in `app/` were automatically added in Rails 3.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that the TestServer has to be in quotes for `config.middleware.use` call.

The answer here helped:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16206347/3467

The Heroku howto is incorrect, sent them an comment to fix it.