# Adding custom data to bugsnag notifications with middleware in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bugsnag

I would like to add a custom Tab to bugsnag for all notifications generated by my rails app.

I cannot use :before_bugsnag_notify because the errors are sometimes generated by models which are being called from resque background jobs.

So, I settled on using middleware and I am running to some issues here:

so I went through this guide here: 
https://bugsnag.com/docs/notifiers/ruby#bugsnag-middleware

and added my middleware at app/middleware as follows:

```
  class CustomMiddleware
    def initialize(bugsnag)
      @bugsnag = bugsnag
    end

    def call(notification)
        puts "doing something"
        @bugsnag.call(notification)
    end
  end
```

The config file for bugsnag is as follows:

in config/initializers/bugsnag.rb:

```
Bugsnag.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = "#{ENV['BUGSNAG_API_KEY']}"
  config.middleware.use "CustomMiddleWare"
end
```

Eventually, I would like to add a tab using add_tab() method before @bugsnag.call(), but now I keep running into the error that I cannot fix:

```
** [Bugsnag] Bugsnag middleware error: undefined method `new' for "CustomMiddleWare":String
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I had to put the method name is strings because of this: 
[Where do you put your Rack middleware files and requires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428343/where-do-you-put-your-rack-middleware-files-and-requires)