# What is wrong with how I'm attempting to load middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleware

I'm trying to write some middleware for a Ruby on Rails app.  Here's what I have:

app/middleware/update_cache.rb:

```
class UpdateCache
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

config/application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path("../boot", __FILE__)
require "rails/all"
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use("UpdateCache")
  end
end
```

Pretty straight-forward; nothing out of the ordinary.  But when I make a request to the rails server, I get this error:

```
undefined method `call' for #<UpdateCache:0x00000003eec1b0>
```

Out of curiosity, I thought I'd try to pass a class instead of a string to `app.middleware.use`, and got this backtrace:

```
/home/fred/my_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<class:Application>': uninitialized constant MyApp::Application::UpdateCache (NameError)
    from /home/fred/my_app/config/application.rb:11:in `<module:MyApp>'
    from /home/fred/my_app/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fred/.gem/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/fred/.gem/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/fred/.gem/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/fred/.gem/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/fred/.gem/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/fred/.gem/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Is app/middlewhere/update_cache.rb the right place to put UpdateCache?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your problem have the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428343/where-do-you-put-your-rack-middleware-files-and-requires

Comment: To me this sounds like there is another class called UpdateCache that is shadowing yours (could be from your app, another gem etc.)

Comment: @user3762171: I saw that post, but to the best of my understanding, I'm following their suggestions verbatim.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @FrederickCheung: Holy crap, that was it!  Wow, I could have been stuck on that for a while.  Submit a response and I'll mark it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably another class in your app (or one of its dependencies) called `UpdateCache` and rails is picking up that one instead.

To verify this you could remove this UpdateCache class and try evaluating `UpdateCache` from the rails console - if this doesn't raise an error then you'll have found your culprit.